# Django restrict user access to related objects

Tags: django, model, permissions

I am writing an application which allows a user to authenticate and view objects only within their organisation. For a `generic.ListView`, I can restrict access with the code below:

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    organisation = models.ForeignKey('Organisation', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Organisation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, null=False, verbose_name="Name")
```

views.py

```
class OrganisationList(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
model = Organisation

def get_queryset(self):
    return Organisation.objects.filter(id=self.request.user.organisation.id)
```

In addition to this view the user will access forms, an API and the django admin interface that require this restriction.

For example, user Brett belongs to Kids Incorporated. When he logs in to the admin panel he can currently also see ACME Corporation but should not be able to do so.

[image: User Brett should not see ACME Corporation]

I have looked at `ModelManager` interface but I am not sure how to get the user request and override
Is there a way to run write one query for all views (DRY) that so that a user will only see their own organisation?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way.

1. Install `django-crequest` package: https://github.com/Alir3z4/django-crequest#installing
2. Create a `model.Manager` within models.py and override the `get_queryset` method

models.py

```
...
from crequest.middleware import CrequestMiddleware

class UserOrganisationManager(models.Manager):
def get_queryset(self):
    request = CrequestMiddleware.get_request()
    return super().get_queryset().filter(id=request.user.organisation.id)


class Organisation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, 
                            unique=True, null=False, verbose_name="Name")
    ...
    objects = UserOrganisationManager()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [groups and permissions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Authentication) for that, a group per organization. And only members of some group can **read** (the permission) objects within their organization group.

This will allow you to have more that one organization for a user or vice-versa. And of course no require any other dependency.

Comment: Hi Raydel, I agree it would be better to have less dependencies. Can you give an example of how to implement this?

Comment: You can find an example in the link I posted.

Comment: I've been through the tutorial and it's a great complement to the official django tutorial, but it doesn't directly address the problem, hence the request for some example / guidance for your suggestion.